# What is the best way to implement client-side paginated API calls with Vertx?

Tags: rest, pagination, vert.x

I have a Vert.x web service that needs to make a series of paginated calls to an external API. The external service implements pagination by including a "next" field in each response -- which is a direct link to the next page of data -- as well as a count of the total number of pages required to fetch all data. Here's an example response:

```
"pagination": {
  "count": 1000,
  "totalPages": 112,
  "next": "https://some-host.com?next=some-long-alphanumeric-hash"
},
"data": [ ... ]
```

After making the first API call, I know the total number of follow-up calls (in this example, 111) as well as the URL to fetch the next page of data. In a synchronous environment, I could just do something like this:

```
Collection aggregatedResults;
int count = 0;
String nextUrl = "";
while (count <= total pages) {
   make next request
   add the chunk of data from this response to the collection
   store the next URL in local variable
   increment count
}
```

My strategy with Vertx is to use `Future`s to represent the result of individual calls, and then chain them together with `CompositeFuture.all()`. This is roughly what I have so far (some code omitted to save space):

```
private String nextUrl; // global String

doFirstCall(client).setHandler(async -> {
    if (async.failed()) {
      // blah
    } else {
        Response response = async.result();
        int totalPages = response.getTotalPages();
        next = response.getNext();

        List<Future> paginatedFutures = IntStream
                .range(0, totalPages - 1)
                .mapToObj(i -> {
                    Promise<Response> promise = Promise.promise();
                    doIndividualPaginatedCall(client, next)
                            .setHandler(call -> {
                                if (call.succeeded()) {
                                    Response chunk = call.result();
                                    next = chunk.getNext(); // store the next URL in global string so it can be accessed within the loop
                                    promise.complete(chunk);
                                } else {
                                    promise.fail(call.cause());
                                }
                            });
                    return promise.future();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        CompositeFuture.all(paginatedFutures).setHandler(all -> {
            if (all.succeeded()) {
                // Do something with the aggregated responses
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I run this code, the first call always succeeds and I store the "next" URL successfully. Then, every subsequent paginated call I make is to the same URL I got from the first call and I see logs like this:

```
Call succeeded. i: 16, next: https://blah.com/blah?filter=next(DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoBQAAAAAAlMYVFjdaM2ducHBaVGJHeWV5ZjRzNGRQMXcAAAAAAJTGNhYzcWlRTDEyeVJZS05PeV84QkJlLTVnAAAAAACUxjYWa3UzUkx1MXZURG1Pc2E5WGt5RG9pdwAAAAAAlMY2FnY4TVhXajlqUmMtWEQwWU1naGZFN3cAAAAAAJTGVxZCWWFUV19XR1RXQ05DRkI0NGw4M0xB)
Call succeeded. i: 17, next: https://blah.com/blah?filter=next(DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoBQAAAAAAlMYVFjdaM2ducHBaVGJHeWV5ZjRzNGRQMXcAAAAAAJTGNhYzcWlRTDEyeVJZS05PeV84QkJlLTVnAAAAAACUxjYWa3UzUkx1MXZURG1Pc2E5WGt5RG9pdwAAAAAAlMY2FnY4TVhXajlqUmMtWEQwWU1naGZFN3cAAAAAAJTGVxZCWWFUV19XR1RXQ05DRkI0NGw4M0xB)
Call succeeded. i: 18, next: https://blah.com/blah?filter=next(DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoBQAAAAAAlMYVFjdaM2ducHBaVGJHeWV5ZjRzNGRQMXcAAAAAAJTGNhYzcWlRTDEyeVJZS05PeV84QkJlLTVnAAAAAACUxjYWa3UzUkx1MXZURG1Pc2E5WGt5RG9pdwAAAAAAlMY2FnY4TVhXajlqUmMtWEQwWU1naGZFN3cAAAAAAJTGVxZCWWFUV19XR1RXQ05DRkI0NGw4M0xB)
```

TLDR: How can I execute a series of paginated API calls, where the URL changes between each call and isn't known until the previous call finishes executing? I've tried using `CompositeFuture.join`, but same effect. I know that for sequential composition, you're supposed to use `compose()`, but how can I compose an unknown number of function calls?

Comment: Is the `next` field present in the response that contains the last page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to mutate `next`

```
if (call.succeeded()) {
    Response chunk = call.result();
    next = chunk.getNext(); // store the next URL in global string so it can be accessed within the loop
    promise.complete(chunk);
}
```

But you're actually reusing the same value you got the first time:

```
next = response.getNext();
```

That's because all your calls are invoked long before even one of them will return.

Since you cannot know the `next` value before the previous call returns, you'll have to implement it in a recursive manner, and drop the `map`:

```
doIndividualPaginatedCall(client, next)
   .setHandler(call -> {
        if (call.succeeded()) {
            Response chunk = call.result();
            next = chunk.getNext(); // store the next URL in global string so it can be accessed within the loop
            promise.complete(chunk);
            doIndividualPaginatedCall(client, next);
       } else {
           promise.fail(call.cause());
       }
  });
```

Please note that I didn't actually compile your code, so there may be more changes you'll have to do for it to actually work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was misunderstanding the API I'm connecting to in this question, and the "next" field does not change between calls. Therefore, this question reduces to "How do I implement async client-side pagination in Vertx, where I *do* know the URL prior to each paginated call?". I'm accepting Alexey's answer because it answered the original question, and posting the rough code I used below in case this helps anyone with the same use case:

```
// start()
doFirstCall(client).setHandler(async -> {
  if (async.succeeded()) {
    Response response = async.result();
    final int totalPages = response.totalPages();
    final String next = response.next();

    // Fire off 'totalPages' async calls and wait for them to come back
    List<Future> paginatedFutures = IntStream
      .range(0, totalPages)
      .mapToObj(i -> {
         Promise<Response> promise = Promise.promise();
         doPaginatedCall(client).setHandler(call -> {
            if (call.succeeded()) {
              promise.complete(call.result());
            }
         });
         return promise.future();
      }).collect(Collectors.toList());

   // Wait for all HTTP calls to come back before continuing
   CompositeFuture.join(paginatedFutures).setHandler(all -> {
      if (all.succeeded()) {
         // Do something with all of the aggregated calls
      }
  });
  }
});

private Future<Response> doFirstCall(WebClient client) {
   Promise<Response> promise = Promise.promise();

   // If call succeeded, promise.complete(response), otherwise fail

   return promise.future();
}

private Future<Response> doPaginatedCall(WebClient client, String nextUrl) {
   Promise<Response> promise = Promise.promise();

   // If call succeeded, promise.complete(response), otherwise fail

   return promise.future();
}
```